# How to access the value of an object inside an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

Here is my code.

```
var a = [   
    {
        name:"john",
        age:18,
        interests:[
            {
                uname: "computer",
                http: "google.com"
            },
            {
                lname:"foo",
                http: "twitter.com"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name:"jack",
        age:21,
        interests:["movies","music"]
    }
]

a.forEach(function(obj){
    for(var key in obj) {
        console.log(key)    
    }
})
```

How do I access the value of "uname"("computer") from the above code using the foreach loop?

Comment: `a[0].interests[0].uname`

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
a.forEach(function(obj){
    for(var key in obj) {
        if (key == 'interests') {
            console.log(obj[key][0].uname);
        }
    }
})
```